# Posting photo from a native ShareDialog in Facebook android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to post an image to the Facebook using SDK v3.6 ShareDialog.

As a result I got com.facebook.FacebookException: Error retrieving image attachment.

I did just like Doc says:

```
    private void ShareDialog(){
    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    //action.setProperty("game", "https://example.com/cooking-app/meal/Lamb-Vindaloo.html");

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon); 
    List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    images.add(bitmap);

    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "cooking-app:cook", "game")
            .setImageAttachmentsForAction(images, true)
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
}
```

And I know I need to add `<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider{Facebook-app-id}"
          android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider" />` in AndroidManifest.xml, but when I did this, there is an error code, `Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Tag <provider> attribute authorities has invalid character '{'.
    - Exported content providers can provide access to potentially sensitive 
     data`

How to add a provider correctly?

Comment: Post your manifest code.

Answer (score 5):

In your `provider` definition, where it says `{Facebook-app-id}` you have to fill in the app id provided to by Facebook.

Comment: <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider{1234567890}" android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider" /> Is it right?

Comment: Without the curly braces: `android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider1234567890"`

Comment: Oh, thanks! Btw, do I need to create a new action on App Dashboard first?

Answer (score 3):

Add the content provider to your manifest.

```
 <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider{Facebook-App-Id}"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Make sure **exported= true** (as above)