# Facebook-Android-SDK v3.6 ShareDialog attach bitmap

Tags: android, image, share, facebook-android-sdk

I've poured through the documentation, and it appears as though it is not possible to simply share a local user generated image through the ShareDialog provided in the SDK?

Can someone confirm if this is indeed the case? If it is possible, how can I do this? I only ask because it is possible to do this through OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder via setImageAttachmentsForAction, but not ShareDialogBuilder.(ex: [Posting photo from a native ShareDialog in Facebook android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227559/posting-photo-from-a-native-sharedialog-in-facebook-android-sdk))

All I want to do is to post a status update with an image, I don't want to create link to another URL, which is required by the OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder.

Comment: This is correct, currently the only way (via a share dialog) is through the open graph action dialog.

Comment: hmm that's a shame, it seems like an obvious feature to have. thanks for that though!

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but here is my solution with the latest Facebook API:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scrat);
            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(image)
                .build();
            SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

            ShareDialog dlg = new ShareDialog(MainActivity.this);
            if(dlg.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)){
                dlg.show(content);
            }
```

Don't forget you have to be logged.